# Replacement for Oracle's `sys_refcursor` in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

Im migrating the procedures from oracle to mysql. Is there any replacement for sys_refcursor in mysql? Please help me out of this issue....

Answer (score 0):

I do not think MySql has the same functionality. As a work-around you can use temp tables

Comment: Thanks for reply.How to use temp tables as a work-around for this in mysql.Can you explain with an example.